# Set up email server for cron job

Tags: email-server, cron, mailman

So I've been running a cron job on a daily basis and I set it up with the MAILTO variable so that I receive an email with the error output if the command ever fails. It was working fine up until today, now Google apparently blocked this mailer service from sending emails to my email account (error message: This message does not have authentication information or fails to pass 550-5.7.1 authentication checks.).

I've been reading that I need to set up some sort of mailing service (example: Mailman) to take care of sending the emails. I agree, but I have no idea how to set this up with a cron job. So how would I go about setting up some email server or service to take care of this?

Comment: ssmtp is a simple very lightweight alternative compared to full fledged mailserver such as Postfix, Exim or the venerable sendmail and should be sufficient to simply deliver your cron messages to a mailhub for delivery

Comment: Thanks. But could you provide some steps as to how to set this up? I'm using a mac machine by the way.